# Get parameter's value of a Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

### The goal

Get parameter's value of a Data Annotation.

### The problem

I don't know the syntax.

### The scenario

There is the following controller on my application:

```
[PermissionsFilter(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

And there is the following method on my application:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    return true;
}
```

What I need seems to be simple: **how do I get the `Administrator` string on the `AuthorizeCore` method?** Is via `httpContext` parameter?

### Knowledge spotlight

The `AuthorizeCore` is within of `PermissionFilters` class that implements `AuthorizeAttribute`. In other words, I'm overriding the `AuthorizeCore` method of `Authorize` attribute to create a new one (PermissionFilters attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use reflection to get the attribute applied to your controller action.  Below is a quick and dirty example of how you could do that:

```
    private string GetPermissionFilerValue()
    {
        object[] attributes = typeof(YourControllerType).GetType().GetMethod("Index").GetCustomAttributes(typeof (PermissionFilterAttribute));

        return attributes[0].Roles;
    }
```

Basically you need to get a reference to your controller's type and then from that, get a reference to the method on your controller.  Once you have that, in the form a MethodInfo object, you can use GetCustomAttributes to get all custom attributes applied to your method or all custom attributes of a specific type.  Once you have your attribute instance you can inspect the Roles property.

As I mentioned, the example above is a very quick and dirty demonstration of how to get an attribute instance for a specific method.  You'll likely need to tailor it to fit it into your specific scenario.

Comment: You'll probably want a more flexible solution that isn't hard coded to the controller type and action method name.  You'll have to figure out how to retrieve those though.

Comment: I get your idea and as you said, your sneak code is a dirty way to perform it. By the way, is this (really) necessary to check if the user is in the right role? (off question)

Comment: If you're using ASP.Net MVC, no, this would definitely not be the preferred method of checking if a user is in a role.  Check out HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("yourRole")

Comment: @chris.house.00 You give me an idea — thanks for this! Anyway, I will need a more flexible way to perform the code that you posted. Do you know what I need to search to get documentation about reflection in Data Annotation?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you're specifically trying to do.  Reflection is a more generic API in .Net that allows you to inspect and act upon types and members.  You could start with MSDN's documentation on the System.Reflection namespace:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx or this overview of reflection:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have one more question, Chris. Why do you get the typeof `PermissionFilterAttribute` instead of `PermissionFilter`? Other peoples 'r adding `Attribute` to the end of Data Annotation's name, and I can't understand why.

Comment: When you apply an attribute class to a method, class, parameter, etc, by convention, the Attribute suffix is omitted.  If you want to work with an attribute class or type outside of that context then you need to use the full name.  Here's a quick sample that hopefully makes this more clear:  http://pastebin.com/hP6zXmxP

Comment: Hmm, got it, Chris. But the strange thing is: when I suffixes something with `Attribute`, VS returns me: `The type or namespace name "PermissionFiltersAttribute" could not be found (...)`. Why?

Comment: Ah, yeah, the standard for custom attribute classes is to use the Attribute suffix but it's not a requirement.  If your PermissionFilters attribute class doesn't adhere to that standard then  you'd just always use PermisionFilters.